# What is the opposite of 'followers'? And the context is NOT social networking sites

Tags: word-usage, word-request, antonyms

I'm not talking about twitter or facebook followers. Here, I'm concerned about calling a person who is not a follower of any great personality.

For instance,

> Lee is a follower of Dalai Lama

but what could fill in the blank here? Tsung does not like Dalai Lama and is not a follower.

> Tsung is ________ of Dalai Lama

I don't want to use *'not'* in the sentence.

---

My homework: The opposite of 'follower' as searched on authentic sources ends up in the word 'leader' but as you clearly see, that does not answer my question.

Comment: Because, almost by definition, "the followers of X" for any given X will be a small percentage of the world's population, being a "*non-follower*" is the ***default** state of humanity*, and we do not have a word for this default state for the same reason we don't have a word for "*people who are under 8 feet tall*" even if once in a while some person or another grows over 8 feet tall. Make sense? That said, if these *non-followers* took some *non-default* action directed at X, such as *opposing* X, you could call them the "***opponents** of X*", or the "***detractors** of X*".

Comment: The risk of forcing a word upon that _default state_ is indeed that you end up with something like _opponent_, which is only true if they actively _oppose_ instead of follow. But the majority of non-followers are probably not _opposing_. (I am, for instance, not an active non-collector of stamps, in the same way I do not actively not-follow any religious leader.) If you want to remain neutral, use _not_. If you want to imply active opposition,  you can use Dan's suggestions.

Comment: You *might* could use something like "indifferent to", "uninfluenced by", "unpersuaded by", or "unaffected by".  It depends on the context I think. These are not noun-antonyms, though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The antonym of *follower* is *leader*; however, you do not need an antonym. You are simply negating the sentence "The Tsung is a follower of the Dalai Lama". As far as I know, there is no single word in English for the concept you are trying to express. We have 'non-believers', but we don't normally have 'non-followers'. I am afraid you'll have to use 'not'.

Comment: Okay. It's better to use 'not' then.

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is [followee (2)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/followee).

> A person who is being followed.
>   ‘tailgaters are fools—if an accident happens, the follower gets the blame, not the followee’

Comment: Please don't simply provide links. Also copy the content as applicable. We are building a reference site for learners, might as well do our best to provide useful and relevant information as much as we can. :)